# How to synchronize org-agenda in emacs with changes on the file system (org-agenda-files)?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, android

I'm trying to synchronize orgzly on android with org-mode/org-agenda setup in emacs on a linux desktop. They are synchronizing via rclone on desktop and [RSAF](https://github.com/chenxiaolong/RSAF) on android.

Right now org-agenda doesn't refresh when files change, which risks overwriting changes made by orgzly. Orgzly has a scheduled synchronization, so after a while it detects changes (and asks whether to use upstream or local version).

I assume that you could create a cron job that will "refresh" org-mode/org-agenda in emacs periodically. Is that correct? If so, could anyone hint me the right command? I've tried `emacsclient --eval '(org-agenda-redo-all "EXHAUSTIVE")'`, but that didn't seem to work (org-agenda still displayed past time).

Comment: Press `g` in the agenda to refresh it.

Comment: You have to evaluate `(org-agenda-redo-all ...)` in the context of the agenda buffer.